# Weird internet connection

Tags: networking, internet

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 (console), and I have been using it for a while but I have currently ran into an issue that has been present for a while now, and I am tired of it.

I host Minecraft servers on this machine, and it works fine. People can connect, I can connect, etc. But, when I try to ping an IP or domain name, it times out.

This is very odd, and I hope we can solve this.

- I have suspected the firewall, but I tried disabling it and it still occurs.
- /etc/network/interfaces: http://pastebin.com/raw/95mGyKY4
- ifconfig: http://pastebin.com/raw/y6q65Abq

If you need more info, please let me know.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Have you tried to `tracepath` where does the ping drop start? Does your server have a public IP? Or you're behind a router with NAT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue!

This was caused by my motherboard. I had just gotten it replaced it works great now.